# Image uploader in extension not saving / uploading image

Tags: magento-1.8, image, controllers

I'm trying to add an image upload to an admin page of an extension following suit from Amasty's Improved Navigation (also the extension that I'm extending)...

After saving the page however, there is no image saved nor uploaded and I'm struggling to see where the problem lies.

My `saveAction` in the controller is the following:-

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('amshopby/page');
    $data   = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($data) {
        $model->setData($data)->setId($id);
        
        try {
            $this->prepareForSave($model);
            
            $cond = array();
            for ($i=0; $i < $model->getNum(); ++$i){
                $cond[] = array(
                    'attribute_code' => $model->getData('attr_' . $i),
                    'attribute_value' => $model->getData('option_' . $i)
                );
            }
            
            $model->setCond(serialize($cond));
            
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
            
            $msg = Mage::helper('amshopby')->__('Page has been successfully saved');
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($msg);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('continue')){
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            }
            else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*');
            }
           
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $id));
        }    
                    
        return;
    }
    
    //upload images
    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'amshopby' . DS;
    $imagesTypes = array('big', 'small', 'medium', 'small_hover', 'main');
    foreach ($imagesTypes as $type){
        $field = 'img_' . $type;
        
        $isRemove = isset($data['remove_' . $field]);
        $hasNew   = !empty($_FILES[$field]['name']);
        
        try {
            // remove the old file
            if ($isRemove || $hasNew){
                $oldName = $model->getData($field);
                if ($oldName){
                     @unlink($path . $oldName);
                     $data[$field] = '';
                }
            }

            // upload a new if any
            if (!$isRemove && $hasNew){
                $newName = $type . $id;
                $newName .= '.' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES[$field]['name'], '.'), 1)); 
           
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($field);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png','gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg'));
                $uploader->save($path, $newName);    
                 
                $data[$field] = $newName;            
            }   
        }
        
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());    
        }
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('amshopby')->__('Unable to find a page to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Every other field on the page saves fine except the image upload (which you can see in the above section from the `//upload images` line onwards).

The following is what I have in my `Form.php` for this field (though I don't expect the issue to lie here):-

```
$fldUpload = $form->addFieldset('upload', array('legend'=> $hlp->__('Image Upload')));
$fldUpload->addField('img_main', 'file', array(
'label'     => $hlp->__('Image'),
'name'      => 'img_main',
'required'  => false,
'after_element_html' => $this->getImageHtml($model->getImgMain()), 
)); 
$fldUpload->addField('remove_img_main', 'checkbox', array(
    'label'     => $hlp->__('Remove Image'),
    'name'      => 'remove_img_main',
    'value'     => 1,
));
```

I've also added `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` to the `_prepareForm` function like so:-

```
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
```

I also use the function below to show the uploaded image on the admin page in the field section:-

```
private function getImageHtml($img)
{
    $html = '';
    if ($img){
        $html .= '<p style="margin-top: 5px">';
        $html .= '<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'amshopby/' . $img .'" />';
        $html .= '</p>';
    } 
    return $html;     
}
```

Once page is saved, the text next to the upload image button just says 'no file chosen' still (and can confirm that nothing is saved in the database nor image uploaded to `/media/amshopby`).

Have I missed something obvious in the controller? The same code is in use for multiple image uploads elsewhere in this extension and working without issue (but in a different controller).

## Edit 18/06/2014

I am one step closer now having managed to get the image uploader in the form  to work although I cannot get the preview of the image to show in the admin form - posted as a [new question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24263/fetching-uploaded-image-in-the-model).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly i didn't have time to go the scripts you have there line by line, BUT It could be that you haven't remember to alter the form to set the multipartbit that is necessary for the file upload.

`$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'post'));`

But if it does have that then you have an issue with your codes and i'd suggest you to use `Zend_Debug::dump($_FILES)` to log out do you get the right data on the submission.

Or `Mage::log($message)` that should output the logs under /etc/logs/system.log

Comment: Did you debug that you get the file info on the post? If you did and the post works then you have a flaw in the saving of the page data as after a quick snoop i noticed that there a  $model->save(); save there. But no saving after the image bit.

Comment: I haven't really figured out what to try and log within the controller to be honest yet but I do think that the issue is something to do with the code relating to the upload images in the controller being in the wrong place. I think it needs to be inside the sections that includes `$model->save();` - is this what you're suggesting also? Thanks.

Comment: That was it, I moved the code for image upload to below `$model->setData($data)->setId($id);` and it is now uploading the file (could see that as I also added logging from your answer `Mage::log("Did we upload the file' . $newName", Zend_Log::INFO, 'img_main.log', true);`. It isn't showing the image on the page though but getting closer now!

Comment: I posted a [follow up question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24263/fetching-uploaded-image-in-the-model) for the last part of this problem (getting the uploaded image to preview in the admin form).

Comment: Cool! Anyways as general tips on debugging: you can pass whole objects to the Mage::log or Zend_Debug::dump so no need to get single values. And also I'd  suggest on dumping / logging always per line and after that just die() to prevent next steps from running and fix issues almost "per step basis". Eg. does this "if" work or does it go to the else. Also a pro tip (or not): you could run "tail -f file" on the console for the log file. It will follow the file updates and output them is it changes.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that, very useful - could you recommend what to debug on the follow up question I linked to? It's not saving the image filename to the database table - I know that the filename is generated correctly and the image uploads - it's just the filename is not inserted into the database - thanks for your help.

Comment: Well id first check the model table has a column for the new value in the database. Ff the field is named in the db like "field_name_here" id try to manually store data to it (note the camelcazing): $model->setFieldNameHere("yay"); add that anywhere and call $model->save() after that and check the database does it save actually. Thought I just noticed: the bit $model->setData($data)->setId($id); should be after the uploading segment. You are calling the save correctly after, but your populating the $data to the model before you add the images to it. But not sure is the db end right here :).

Comment: Brilliant, that's it perfectly. Please add as an answer on the other question so I can accept it :) (I will reply in more detail in the comment to your answer then).

Comment: Now the remove image checkbox doesn't work (lol)...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the image upload to work in the form by placing the relevant code into the `SaveAction()` function before the `prepareForSave($model)` like so:-

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('amshopby/page');
    $data   = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($data) {
        $model->setData($data)->setId($id);

    //upload images
    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'amshopby' . DS;
    $imagesTypes = array('big', 'small', 'medium', 'small_hover', 'main');
    foreach ($imagesTypes as $type){
        $field = 'img_' . $type;

        $isRemove = isset($data['remove_' . $field]);
        $hasNew   = !empty($_FILES[$field]['name']);

        try {
            // remove the old file
            if ($isRemove || $hasNew){
                $oldName = $model->getData($field);
                if ($oldName){
                     @unlink($path . $oldName);
                     $data[$field] = '';
                }
            }

            // upload a new if any
            if (!$isRemove && $hasNew){
                $newName = $type . $id;
                $newName .= '.' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES[$field]['name'], '.'), 1)); 

                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($field);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png','gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg'));
                $uploader->save($path, $newName);    

                $data[$field] = $newName;            
            }   
        }

        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());    
        }
    }

        try {
            $this->prepareForSave($model);

            $cond = array();
            for ($i=0; $i < $model->getNum(); ++$i){
                $cond[] = array(
                    'attribute_code' => $model->getData('attr_' . $i),
                    'attribute_value' => $model->getData('option_' . $i)
                );
            }

            $model->setCond(serialize($cond));

            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            $msg = Mage::helper('amshopby')->__('Page has been successfully saved');
            //log
            Mage::log("Did we upload the file' . $newName", Zend_Log::INFO, 'img_main.log', true);
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($msg);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('continue')){
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            }
            else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*');
            }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $id));
        }    

        return;
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('amshopby')->__('Unable to find a page to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```