# Field value in admin form not saving to database

Tags: adminhtml, model, adminform, image-preview

This is what I'm trying to achieve as the end result by the way:-

[image: Magento Image Upload Preview]

I think I may have just realised why `$this->getImageHtml($model->getImgMain())` returns nothing. Is this meant to be getting the value from the database? If so, there is no value stored in the database. So the image uploader is uploading the image but not saving the name in the database. I think I'm getting somewhere?

## Edit

I can confirm, that the value as per above is returned empty because the image filename is not being saved to the database:-

```
        $fldUpload = $form->addFieldset('upload', array('legend'=> $hlp->__('Image Upload')));
        $fldUpload->addField('img_main', 'file', array(
        'label'     => $hlp->__('Image'),
        'name'      => 'img_main',
        'required'  => false,
        'after_element_html' => $this->getImageHtml($model->getImgMain()),
        )); 
        $fldUpload->addField('remove_img_main', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'     => $hlp->__('Remove Image'),
            'name'      => 'remove_img_main',
            'value'     => 1,
        ));
```

And I created the table in the database `img_main` and whilst the image uploads, the filename is not saved to the database...

Really stumped on this one, I know the image filename is being generated correctly, I know that the field name is the same as the table name in the database. I can't figure out why the image filename is not being saved in the database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the necessary bit to actually write the data to the model/table.

On line `$data[$field] = $newName;` it alters the `$data` array that is used to store values pair and later you should call `$model->setData($data)` and then you need to actually save with `$model->save()`;

You could pass a single value to the `$models` table column with  `$model->setImgMain("text here");`. *Note the camelcazing*. After saving you could call `$model->getImageMain()` to get the stored value.

Comment: You've been a big help in helping me get this function to save properly - thanks. The 'Remove image' checkbox though does not delete the image on save (that's all that doesn't work now) - the entire current version of the `saveAction` function is in this [pasteBin](http://pastebin.com/cc5Qhc2G) - is there anything that sticks out that could be the cause can you see please? Thanks.